# How to match only 2nd result?

Tags: regex

I have filenames, e.g. `ABC_2014_09_EFG.pdf`

and my program (Enfocus Switch) only allows me to define a regex, where it uses always the first match as the result.

What I want is, to match the number `09`.

I tried already `_[0-9]{2}_`, but then I get the underscores in the result too. I need only the two numbers, how do I do that? Anyone a clue? Already trying here for several hours..

Comment: does Enfocus respect`(?:)` (non-capturing groups)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it with a look behind `/(?<=\d{4}_)(\d+)/`

this will look for fourdigits followed by an underscore and then select the following digits

Here is a short explanation how it works:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JSq6dQQ6kFHozw6s)

·

Another approach could be the usage of a lookahead:
`(\d{2})(?=_\D+)`

this will look for two digits followed by an underscore followed by some non-digits
[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SZ0IQnCGxYpeJKJs)

Comment: well, it seems enfocus supports look aheads (http://www.enfocus.com/manuals/UserGuide/SW/11/enUS/Switch/en-us/reference/r_regular_expressions.html), so I updated my answer

Comment: The 2nd approach works. Thank you very much, you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to capture the last number which was preceded by an `_`,

```
.*_([0-9]+).*?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF1hG1)

**OR**

you could use positive lookahead and lookbehind to match only the two digit number present in your input string,

```
(?<=_)\d{2}(?=_)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oK8sR0)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=_)` Looks after `_` symbol.
- `\d{2}` Checks if  there is any two digit number is following `_` symbol.
- `(?=_)` checks if that two digit number is followed by an `_`. It would match the digits only if both conditions are satisfied.

**OR**

If your language supports `\K`, then use it instead of a lookbehinds

```
_\K\d{2}(?=_)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rM7hZ3)

Comment: it seems enfocus does not support lookbehinds

Comment: @bukfixart does it supports `\K`?

Comment: no it does not seem so (http://www.enfocus.com/manuals/UserGuide/SW/11/enUS/Switch/en-us/reference/r_regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

**This should work in Enfocus Switch:**

```html
function jobArrived( s : Switch, job : Job )
{
 var filename = job.getName( );

 var numberRE = /^\w+\_(\d+)\_\w+\.pdf$/g; 
 numberRE.search( filename );
 var number = numberRE.cap(1);

 job.log(1,"Number is: "+number);

}
```